# Application not to be shown in task bar

Tags: c#, .net, windows

My project is in C# .Net and we do not want to show selected application on Task Bar. i.e has UI, but client wants it should not be displayed on Task Bar.

Can you please suggest any way.

@Edited question

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF?

Comment: Its Winform application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the form's [ShowInTaskbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx) property to `False` either via the designer or by code (`this.ShowInTaskbar = false;`).

Comment: This is the better answer, simply because you are the only one that provided the link to the documentation.